# OneHotEncoding transformation interpretation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to understand the output of the onehotencoding process via python and scikit-learn.  I believe that I get the idea of one hot encoding.  I.e., convert discrete values into extended feature vectors with a value of 'on' to identify membership of a classification.  Perhaps I got that wrong, which is confusing me but that's my understanding.

So, from the documentation here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

I see the following example:

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
>>> enc = OneHotEncoder()
>>> enc.fit([[0, 0, 3], [1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]])  
OneHotEncoder(categorical_features='all', dtype=<... 'numpy.float64'>,
       handle_unknown='error', n_values='auto', sparse=True)
>>> enc.n_values_
array([2, 3, 4])
>>> enc.feature_indices_
array([0, 2, 5, 9])
>>> enc.transform([[0, 1, 1]]).toarray()
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Could someone please explain how the data [[0, 0, 3], [1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]] ends up being transformed into [[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]?

How is the transformation argument [0, 1, 1] used?

Many thanks for any help with this

Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... after further digging, here is my attempt at clarifying one way of understanding this and answering it for others.

1) The original data set is [0, 0, 3], [1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]

2) You then need to reduce these down (by position) to a list of unique ordered values:

So...

```
For position 1 (0, 1, 0, 1) --> [0, 1]
For position 2 (0, 1, 2, 0) --> [0, 1, 2]
For position 3 (3, 0, 1, 2) --> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Now, when transforming this, you simply compare each positional item in the transformed array to the position in the list of unique ordered items

For the transformed array [0, 1, 1]

```
The first '0' generates a [1, 0] ('0' matches value in position one, not position two)
The next '1' generates a [0, 1, 0] ('1' only matches value in position two)
the last '1' generates a [0, 1, 0, 0] ('1' only matches value in position two)
```

Put together, this equates to a [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0].

I've tried this with a number of other data sets, and the logic is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The main goal of one hot encoding is for **categorical features**, where there is no spatial relation between numbers, they are not continuos. So if a feature has value 1 it does not means that it is closer to 2 than 3.

To avoid that we must create a column for each value that a feature can have in a binary way. One possibility to convert categorical features to features that can be used with `scikit-learn` estimators is to use a one-of-K or one-hot encoding. This estimator transforms each categorical feature with `m` possible values into `m` binary features, with only one active.

So, in your example, note that what you are transforming is the array: `[0, 1, 1]`.

Remember that the transformation will make this array binary to the possible encoding, resulting in the array: `[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]`

The first and second ones can have 2 values, while the third can have 4 values (note that to fit we pass only 3 (0, 2, 3) and in the transform we pass 1 as well.

So, the first two elements explain the first feature, the next two explain the second feature and the last four explain the third feature.

Comment: Thanks for the response Silvio.  Your first 2 paragraphs convinces me that I do have the right idea about one hot encoding.  What I still don't understand is how the resultant array was arrived at.

I see no relationship between the [0, 1, 1] and the transformation.  Is the transformation broken into groups of 3? Can you possibly explain how it got to that result?  I have no idea.

Comment: Yes. It is split in 3 groups. The first and second ones can have 2 values, while the third can have 4 values (note that to fit we pass only 3 (`0`, `2`, `3`) and in the transform we pass `1` as well. So, the first two elements explain the first feature, the next two explain the second feature and the last four explain the third feature.

Comment: Thanks again for adding more information, but I'm afraid it confuses further. I don't see where (0, 2, 3) comes from in your answer (or my original question) and it's unclear why the 1st and 2nd have 2 values, while the 3rd has 4 values.